# Cannot access second network interface using url

Tags: networking, iptables, ubuntu-16.04

I have a vps running Ubuntu with two network interfaces.

This is the **ifconfig** output after enabling the second network interface:

```
ens32     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:a8:36:67  
          inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fea8:3667/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1883513 errors:0 dropped:280 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:362667 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:251522994 (251.5 MB)  TX bytes:72543049 (72.5 MB)

ens34     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:9b:65:a0  
          inet addr:10.20.96.88  Bcast:10.20.97.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe9b:65a0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:281993 errors:0 dropped:85 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:58 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18905402 (18.9 MB)  TX bytes:4380 (4.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:12848 (12.8 KB)  TX bytes:12848 (12.8 KB)
```

I have a server binding on port 9601 which is accessible with http://192.168.1.20:9601, however http://10.20.96.88:9601 is unreachable.

**ip route** output:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev ens32 onlink 
10.20.96.0/23 dev ens34  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.20.96.88 
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens32  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.20
```

**ufw status** output:

```
Status: inactive
```

**ping 10.20.96.88** output:

```
PING 10.20.96.88 (10.20.96.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.96.88: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
```

Comment: check service is bind on all the IP's may be it is restricted to primary IP only.

Comment: service is bind on 0.0.0.0 that means all  IP's

Comment: hmm. check if there is any firewall blocking the connections on the port.

Comment: ufw says: Status: inactive

Comment: can you ping it? (10.20.96.88) also there might be a firewall between the server and your machine..

Comment: yeah! i can . I will add the ping output in the question body!

Comment: also you can try to run nmap to see open ports or use netcat (from the machine you are trying to access the url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use this IP as dedicated IP to communicate some specific server,
you should maybe define **static routes**.